# Migration and upgrade from 2007 to 2010 while preserving version history

Tags: 2007, 2010, migration

We are using Microsoft out of the box 2007.  We have sites and subsite with document libraries that have been turned into a lowest form of a document management process.  Workflows are not used but version history and check in, check out has been utilized to track the documents from draft to final.

We will need to move the existing content from the server to a new server that will be upgraded to 2010 during the migration.

Is there a method to first preserve the version history of all of the current site's content? Will there be an issue when upgrading to 2010?

Is there an easy way to archive documents off of SharePoint with their version history?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading using what is called Database attach should be perfect for you.

[Here is one article describing the process](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nitinsha/archive/2010/07/27/migration-from-sharepoint-2007-to-sharepoint-2010.aspx)